# How to refresh the table after button click in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I'm creating a script that retrieves data from api. everything was successful, but when I wanted to enter another film title it didn't want to refresh the existing data but added new data to the previous data.

```
function loadContent() {
        let $ = jQuery;
        let id = $('#titless').val();
        var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=b97618b9d94f7f1090189b207f83ce52&language=en-US&query=" + id + "&page=1&include_adult=false";
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                $.each(data.results, function(i, item) {
                    $('#atas').each(function() {
                        $('<div />', {
                            'class': 'col-md-2 my-2 mx-2 align-center',
                            'id': 'yaa',
                            'style': 'border: solid;',
                            // 'html' : ``,
                            'html': [
                                `<img class="card-img-top" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/${data.results[i].poster_path}">
                                <h3 class="title">${data.results[i].title}</h3>
                                <h1 class="title">${data.results[i].id}</h1>
                                `
                            ],
                            appendTo: this
                        })
                    });
                });
            });
    }
```

this is my html script

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-4">Punten</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-dark">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col my-4 d-flex justify-content-container">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titless">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-4" onclick="loadContent()">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <div id="atas" class="card-body row">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I always get worried when I see code like `$('#atas').each(`. `$('#atas')` should return a single element, since IDs must be unique to the document, so calling `each` on the result indicates a misunderstanding of that. Since you're also inside an `each` of `data.results` and adding a `div` to which you're setting a static ID, it seems justified. It may also be why your code is failing to refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to clear the previous content with [empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Also, you don't need the `each` method over `#atas` since it's a unique element, just append your new elements like this: `$('#atas').append(newElement);`

```js
function loadContent() {
        let $ = jQuery;
        let id = $('#titless').val();
        var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=b97618b9d94f7f1090189b207f83ce52&language=en-US&query=" + id + "&page=1&include_adult=false";
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                /* SOLUTION */
                $('#atas').empty();
                $.each(data.results, function(i, item) {
                    $('#atas').append(
                        $('<div />', {
                            'class': 'col-md-2 my-2 mx-2 align-center',
                            'id': 'yaa',
                            'style': 'border: solid;',
                            // 'html' : ``,
                            'html': [
                                `<img class="card-img-top" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/${data.results[i].poster_path}">
                                <h3 class="title">${data.results[i].title}</h3>
                                <h1 class="title">${data.results[i].id}</h1>
                                `
                            ]
                        })
                    );
                });
            });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-4">Punten</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-dark">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col my-4 d-flex justify-content-container">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titless">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-4" onclick="loadContent()">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <div id="atas" class="card-body row">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```